# Error routing when deploy web asp.net MVC on IIS 6, windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, web-deployment

When deploy asp.net mvc on iis 6 and windows server 2003

-I have installed mvc 3 on server
-Set the properties of some mvc dll CopyLocal =true
-add manual mime type for web app deploy by .mvc and .net 4.0

what am i miss? that can't understand routing of mvc.

Comment: Which specific errors are you getting?

Comment: http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-yWHA-rPsmAM/UgdaVHNmYII/AAAAAAAAAhY/66WO507q3ro/w346-h192/Image+1.png

Comment: so you don't get any error, but just see the content of the directory? - are you sure, you execute the routine to initialize the routes on application start? Also there are some things you might need to configure but there are lot's of blogs about it out there (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/)